# Xtext: Using syntactic predicates with cross-reference

Tags: grammar, predicate, xtext, cross-reference

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the syntactic predicates.

My grammar is:

```
Rule:
    'terminalOne' (name=ID ':')?
    (field='terminalTwo' | myReference=[Something])? (anotherField=RuleTwo TOK_SEMI);
```

Which produces a non-LL(*) conflict.

I tried to put '=>' in-front of:

```
(anotherField=RuleTwo TOK_SEMI)
```

But it doesn't seem to help.

How can I solve it with syntactic predicates?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give a complete minimal reproducing grammar

Comment: well what grammar is quite huge,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did some shortening (your way of left factoring looks very unusal

```
RuleA:
    'terminalA' (name=ID ':')?
    ((->fieldA=ID passedParams+=AdditiveExpression (',' passedParams+=AdditiveExpression)*)
    |
    ((fieldB='t' | fieldC='q')? (fieldD=AdditiveExpression ";")));


AdditiveExpression returns BExpression :
    RuleB
    ({BBinaryOpExpression.leftExpr=current} functionName=("+" | "-") rightExpr=RuleB)*
    ;

RuleB returns BExpression
    : PostopExpression 
    | RuleC
    ; 

RuleC returns BExpression : {BUnaryOpExpression} 
    functionName="-" expr=UnaryOrPrimaryExpression
    ;

PostopExpression returns BExpression :
    PrimaryExpression ({BUnaryPostOpExpression.expr=current} functionName = ("++"))?
    ;

PrimaryExpression returns BExpression:
    c=constant
  | myID=ID '(' myFieldB+=AdditiveExpression (',' myFieldB+=AdditiveExpression)* ')'
    | myP=ID (operator+='['intvalue=INT operator+=']')?
    | operator+='(' additiveExpression=AdditiveExpression operator+=')'
    | operator+='someOperator' operator+='(' additiveExpression=AdditiveExpression operator+=')';


constant:
    booleanValue='FALSE'
    | booleanValue='TRUE'
    | integerValue=INT;
```